# How to enter .subckt model in Ltspice?

Tags: ltspice, subcircuit

This is a LTSpice model I created for a single electron transistor macro model:

```
.subckt SET 1 2 3  

+pi=3.1415926535897932846  
+CF1=40 ; 2CG/e  
+CI2=0.2e-9  
+CR2=100e+6  
+CVp= 0.02  
V2 5 3 DC CVp  
V3 7 3 DC ‘-CVp’   
D4 2 8 DIODE  
D5 3 8 DIODE  
RR1 1 3 R= ‘CR1+CR2*cos(CF1*pi*V(2,3))’  
RR2 1 4 R= ‘CVp/(CI2-2*CVp/(CR1+CR2*cos(CF1*pi*V(2,3))))’  
RR3 1 6 R= ‘CVp/(CI2-2*CVp/(CR1+CR2*cos(CF1*pi*V(2,3))))’  
D2 4 5 DIODE  
D3 7 6 DIODE  
.MODEL DIODE D(N=0.01)   
.ends
```

I got error message that symbols `RR1`, `RR2`, and `RR3` are undefined. What does that error mean and why did I get it?

Comment: Hello Haider, welcome to EE.SX. Please see the [help center](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help) for information on how to ask good questions. There are a dozen or more SPICE packages all of which are slightly different and use slightly different syntaxes. I assume from `.param` you are using LTspice, but this should be stated explicitly. Use the "edit" button below your question to make changes. How are you entering this into LTspice? As a separate file? And the text is missing some linefeeds.

Answer (score 1):

For most simulators the first line in any spice file should be an asterisk *, and is always a comment line.

I do not think you should put the R= part in the resistor definition lines.  The lines should work fine like this:

```
R<rname> <node1> <node2> <r_value>
```

For example:

```
RR1 1 3 'CR1+CR2*cos(CF1*pi*V(2,3))'
```

If this does not work, try defining the expression as a parameter first:

```
.PARAM R1VALUE='CR1+CR2*cos(CF1*pi*V(2,3))'
```

then define resistor values like:

```
RR1 1 3 R1VALUE
```

Also, it looks like in LTspice the .ends should have the subcircuit name afterwards, i.e.:

```
.ends SET
```

For particular nuances of each simulator check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks jbord39 for answer , That suggestion still error saying that cant't solve .PARAM R1VALUE='CR1+CR2*cos(CF1*pi*V(2,3))'

Comment: I think ltspce doesn't like that expression of resistance voltage dependent R1VALUE='CR1+CR2*cos(CF1*pi*V(2,3))'

Comment: Yes that sounds reasonable, I would expect the proper way to handle this to vary between simulators.  I guess check the documentation and see if any examples are given for voltage dependent parameters.